# set jquery UI slider scrollbar vertically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use the jquery UI slider scrollbar.

in the jquery UI site I see an example only for a horizontal slider scrollbar.

is it possible to set it up also vertically?

Answer (score 2):

Set orientation property of slider to vertical.

```
 $( "#YourHtmlControlId" ).slider({
   value: 60,
   orientation: "horizontal",
   range: "min",
   animate: true
 });
```

Refer this [link](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical)

Comment: thanks,what the range stand for? the height of my div where at the point I want to asd the scrollbar?

Comment: Whether the slider represents a range. It supports multiple type boolean and string (min and max).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the slider, assign:
orientation: 'horizontal'